# MapBox - PropertyFactory.iconImage() with Custom Icons uploaded on MapBox Studio?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm working on an Android app and I'm using MapBox.
I was creating a layer and I passed as argument to PropertyFactory.iconImage() the name of an icon I uploaded on MapBox Studio. 
However it doesn't appear on Map. Why?

```
List<Feature> b=featureCollection.features();
SymbolLayer myLayer = new SymbolLayer("dada", "geojson-source");
System.out.println("cvb"+b.get(0).getStringProperty("poi")+"-15");
mapBoxMap.getStyle().addLayer(
     myLayer.withProperties(
         PropertyFactory.iconImage("cvb"+b.get(0).getStringProperty("poi")+"-15")
         ).withFilter(Expression.eq(Expression.get("selected"),Expression.literal(false))));
```

"b.get(0).getStringProperty("poi")" returns "lodging"

It's not a geojson problem, I've already checked that.

From MapBox Studio:
[ScreenImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vzif.png)

Comment: What source are you specifying for the new layer being added? If the layer does not reference an underlying source containing information about where the markers should be located on the map, then it is expected behavior that no icons will display even if they are included in the style's sprite (as yours are, per the screenshot from Mapbox Studio). It's also worth making sure that you published the changes to your map style after adding the "cvblodging-15" icon by clicking the blue "Publish" button in the upper righthand corner of the Studio interface.

Comment: Hi @AdrianaBabakanian, thanks for replying me. Yes, after the icon's upload, I clicked on button Publish and I was using a geojson as source. (source = new GeoJsonSource("geojson-source", geojsonstring); )
My map was able to show default icons, not the custom ones.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong? I'm running into the same behavior.

Comment: @NickK9 do you still need? It was long time ago but i can look into code what i changed since then

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ultimately [solved it by waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77167143/1749551). So no, I don’t need you to look anymore. Thanks, though!